# Looking for a variety of Windows Form tutorials for visual studio.NET C++

Tags: .net, c++, visual-studio, winforms, winapi

Looking for a variety of Windows Form (winforms) tutorials for visual studio.NET C++

I found a few basic ones:
[How to: Create a Windows Forms Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235634%28VS.80%29.aspx)
[Walkthrough: Retrieving Dialog Box Information Collectively Using Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cakx2hdw%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)

Any others?

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many excellent books available.  Maybe you are looking [for videos](http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos.aspx)?  Start at the bottom.  You are not going to find anything at all that will be specific to C++/CLI, just about nobody uses that language to create WF projects.